# How to remove qgvdial (QT Google Voice Dialer)?

Tags: uninstall

I've been having problems trying to remove qgvdial ([QT Google Voice Dialer](https://code.google.com/p/qgvdial/)) since 11.04 and now I'm at 12.04 with still the same problem. I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
qgvdial
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of qgvdial. I found this question because I searched on Google for qgvdial. Please see the project page at http://code.google.com/p/qgvdial/ to make a bug report.

```
dpkg -P --force-all qgvdial
```

That should purge it.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you installed it via `dpkg -i 'package-name'` so try: `dpkg -r 'qgvdial`.

Comment: I tried as above. Here's is the result.

Comment: Removing qgvdial ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qgvdial.prerm: 2: /var/lib/dpkg/info/qgvdial.prerm: /usr/bin/qgv-util: not found
dpkg: error processing qgvdial (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
chmod: cannot access `/usr/bin/qgv-tp': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/usr/bin/qgv-util': No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/qgvdial.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/qgvdial.postinst: /usr/bin/qgv-util: not found

Comment: As well as: dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgvdial   -sorry couldn't add everything in the same box.